# Having troubles implementing a reset button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, reset

I would like to add a reset button where I have put the close program button, but I'm not sure how to do it. I just want it to bring the current tab to its original state before the confirm button was pressed.

```
public class A5 extends JPanel {

public A5() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    //creating tabbed pane
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    //calling question 1 tab method
    JComponent q1 = makeq1panel("Question 1");
    q1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 150));
    tabbedPane.addTab("Question 1", q1);
    add(tabbedPane);    
}


private JComponent makeq1panel(String question) {
    //making panel and title for it
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Enter a number and press confirm");
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(title);
    //spinner for input
    int spinnerstart = 1;
    SpinnerModel number = new SpinnerNumberModel(spinnerstart, spinnerstart - 1, spinnerstart + 50, 1);
    final JSpinner spin = addSpinner(panel,number);
    //confirm button
    JButton btconfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    btconfirm.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String output = null;
            //checking if value is correct
            int inputINT = (Integer)spin.getValue();
            if (inputINT <10 && inputINT >1) 
                output = "True";
            else output = "False";
            //Question output
            JLabel d2 = new JLabel("Output: " + output);
            java.awt.Font subfont = new java.awt.Font("Dialog",Font.BOLD,14);
            d2.setFont(subfont);
            d2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(d2);
            //reset button
            JButton btclose = new JButton("Close Program");
            btclose.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            //adding close button and refreshing
            panel.add(btclose);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    panel.add(btconfirm);
    return panel;
}



private static void makewindow() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Assignment 5");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Add content to the window.
    frame.add(new A5(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

static protected JSpinner addSpinner(Container c, SpinnerModel model) {
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
    c.add(spinner);

    return spinner;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //run it
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            makewindow();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you've made any attempt yet to implement this. Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried a bunch of messy stuff in the button like removeAll(); and then refreshing, then I tried to call the original method that draws the window to see if it would draw over it again but I couldn't get it to work. I wasn't sure If I should put broken code to see where I was messing around or the code that works it could be run to see what I mean

Comment: What you need to do is write down exactly what it means for your program to be "reset". What precise specific logical steps need to be done. And then you need to try to implement each of those steps in code, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

After executing `System.exit(0);` statement your program will be terminate as well as JVM, so the operation will not proceed after this statement.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the original question?

Comment: Read the comment of reset button.

Comment: That is a comment but likely for a button that has yet been implemented. He likely has to implement both a reset and a close button, but from this and his other questions, I don't  think that the original poster has any clue as to what he is doing. He really needs to read a Java book more than anything.

Comment: I was using that instead because I couldn't find a way to implement a reset button, kinda like a placeholder. Sorry for being unclear